# Merge key and value of array index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
['foo'=>'bar','baz'=>'bat']
```

im trying to determine an elegant way (not using a standard forloop, prefer learning php array functions) to result in:

```
['foo: bar','baz: bat']
```

as you can see, the key and the value are joined together separated by a `:`

seems pretty simple, just cant figure out how to do this using an array function format. just trying to gain experience in php functions. i imagine its using `implode` somehow but im trying to figure out how to join the key and value together into one.

i'm on php 8.0

Comment: How about `array_map()`? `implode()` doesn't consider array keys.

Comment: @GigiSan: array_map does not work with keys.

Comment: @lukas.j You can use `array_map()` : see https://3v4l.org/KNCJa

Comment: `not using a standard forloop`, somehow a `foreach` is the most performant solution as it doesn't need to use `array_keys` to loop again the array in `array_map()`

Comment: @ikhvjs most likely is the most performant yes, just trying to expand my learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using [`array_map()`](https://php.net/array_map):

```
$arr = ['foo'=>'bar','baz'=>'bat'];
$combine = array_map(fn($k, $v) => "$k: $v", array_keys($arr), array_values($arr));
print_r($combine);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo: bar
    [1] => baz: bat
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [ 'foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bat' ];

$result = [];

array_walk($arr, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
  $result[] = "$key: $value";
});
```